# Why / how does a printf call change result of my function?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

First of I just started with C, so maybe I'm missing something really stupid.

But I have the following problem:

I have function, that only gives me the right solution, if I have a printf-call in it. Without that call it produces the wrong result.

I had a few in the code to check for errors, and then removed them. So my first thought was, that I also deleted some essential code, my next one was that I changed a variable or something, when using them in my printf-calls.

But all that was not the case, a simple "printf("test");" is enough to make the function do, what I want. Which is nice, but of course I want to find the problem, especially since the next time it might now work.

I guess my question is, why does a printf-call effect my function this much? Is there a general reason?

Below my code:

```
void mergesort(int* array, size_t len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    printf("test");

    size_t len2 = len / 2;

    int array_left[len2];
    int array_right[len-len2];
    size_t len_left;

    for (len_left = 0; len_left < len2; len_left++)
    {
        array_left[len_left] = array[len_left];
    }

    for (size_t i = len2; i < len; i++)
    {
        array_right[i-len2] = array[i];
    }

    mergesort(array_left, len_left);
    mergesort(array_right, len - len_left);

    size_t counter_left = 0;
    size_t counter_right = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (array_left[counter_left] <= array_right[counter_right])
        {
            array[i] = array_left[counter_left];
            counter_left++;            
        }
        else
        {
            array[i] = array_right[counter_right];
            counter_right++;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Where are your includes? Where is `main`? Which output do you get with which input, and which output do you expect? Please show a [MCVE]. Read this: [ask].

Comment: You should test counter_left and counter_right not to exceed len_left and len - len_left.

Comment: Check for out of bounds array indexes. Accessing an array with out of bounds indexes results in _undefined bahaviour_ which includes "apparently working fine_.

Comment: looks like a minimal reproducible example to me, I don't need the `int main{}` to understand this question. In addition, in these cases, reducing the amount of code won't help solving the issue because the code itself is too buggy, it itself has to be debugged.

Comment: @NadavS the problem (or a part of it) could be in the calling code.

Comment: True, but the question was "how can `printf` affect my function", not "debug my program please".

Comment: If we have undefined behaviour anything can happen, for example adding a `printf` make the function appear to work.

Comment: To fix the actual bug, try replacing `if (array_left[counter_left] <= array_right[counter_right])` with `if (counter_right == len - len_left || counter_left < len_left && array_left[counter_left] <= array_right[counter_right])`. (I know this isn't the actual question.)

Comment: Ronald @Ian Abbott, yeah that was the problem in the code. Was think of the possibility of uneven arrays (both number amount and size of them) earlier, but forgot about. Thx.

But still wonder about the printf. Is there a special reason NadavS answer has zero upvotes and was even in the minus for a while?

Answer (score 0):

A stack overflow. The call to `printf` pads your stack with non-essential variables so overriding doesn't interrupt it. Try to reach a minimal reproducible example or using a debugger to isolate the bug.

Edit: I know the bug is `array_right[i-len2] = array[i]`, the asker didn't ask to debug the code but how can `printf` affect the result.

Comment: Why would you say ```that array_right[i-len2] = array[i]``` is wrong? Or what should be done instead?

I have seen this in other solution, when I tried to find my error. And problem could apperently be fixed, without messing with it.